# Can we import *.cod file as a library for 3rd Part application?

Tags: build, blackberry

Can we import  *.cod file as a library for 3rd Party application?

If it possible then how?

Answer (score 4):

You can only use jar as 3rd party libraries referenced in project.
(Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JAR's)

On the other hand, you can reference library project in application project if they are in the same workspace.
(Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Projects->Add...)